# XLWINGS: How to get the username reserving writing access on an excel file in python?

Tags: python-3.x, pywin32, xlwings

I'm working with the xlwings library for python to do some work on an excel sheet and need to check beforehand if the file is opened by another user and if so, find out who it is.

Getting to know whether the file is read only is easy enough, as one can use the "read_only"-attribute of the workbook's api object and it returns True or False.

Getting the user name in theory is just as easy by using WriteReservedBy on the api-objec, but for some reason it returns my own name as the user reserving writing access even though the file is opened by someone else and I can only open it in read-only.

It's hard for me to find proper documentation on the topic, as I'm having trouble even finding documentation on the methods I'm using in this example.

The code I've used to test it so far is simple enough:

```
import xlwings as xw

app = xw.App()
wb = app.books.open(r"path\to\file.xlsx")
wb_api = wb.api  # this is a win32 COM object as far as I can tell
wb_api.ReadOnly  # returns True, as it should
wb_api.WriteReservedBy  # returns my own name - perhaps because I opened the book ealier?
wb.close()
app.quit()
```

If I open the file manually in Excel, it shows a warning the file is opened by another user with the proper name instead of my own. I would expect WriteReservedBy to do the same, but alas, it does not.

Is there perhaps a possibility to check for that in another way? Or maybe a possibility to check on the file without opening it first?